# Passing Isolate/ControlPort through MethodChannel

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin, dart-isolates

Within our flutter app we are doing some background processing. For that, we need to create new flutter isolate in our native code so we can run code when activity is not open, based on this guide: https://medium.com/@chetan882777/initiating-calls-to-dart-from-the-native-side-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugin-7d46aed32c47

Now, to not duplicate code and to not cause any concurrency issues, we would also like to have access to that background processing isolate from main flutter UI isolate. That way we can begin processing from both native code and from flutter UI code.

However, there does not seem to be a way for native to pass this Isolate / ControlPort to the main UI side so it can communicate with it. Is there a way I can achieve this (communicate to the same Isolate from both native and UI side)?

From what I see, only way to do this would require native to be the broker between the two sides (send the task to native and then native sends it back to the other side), but it seems like a lot of hassle for one flutter talking to another flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this is the [IsolateNameServer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/IsolateNameServer-class.html).

One side can call `IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName()` and other side can then send messages to that port via `IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName()`